# Hortonworks: Should I create users such as hdfs, hive in Ambari?

Tags: hive, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari, hortonworks-sandbox

I'm new to Hortonworks HDP; I have the following questions:

1. There are some users that if I don't create them, then even admin can't perform.  For example, unless I create a user called hdfs in ambari, I won't be able to do a lot of the file/folder operations on HDFS.  Should I create such users?  Is this how others manage the cluster?
2. In Hive interface, I have to click on the 'Execute' button each time I want the query to be executed.  Is there a keyboard shortcut for execute?  For example in Oracle SQL developer,  you press Ctrl+Enter to execute the query.  That's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Ambari creates required users automatically. But you can set up LDAP if you have such need.

Comment: You are correct, but how do I login as those users?  There doesn't seem anyway to become those users.

Comment: does `su hdfs` work for you? 
https://ambari.apache.org/1.2.5/installing-hadoop-using-ambari/content/ambari-kerb-2-2-2b.html

Answer (score 0):

Ranger is also available in hortonworks, Using the Apache Ranger console, security can easily manage using policies for access to files, folders, databases, tables, or column. These policies can be set for individual users or groups and then enforced consistently across HDP stack.